# Validating changed queryset not working - Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-validation

I want to do the following:
A user sees all `eventrecords` he previously created on one page and can edit them.

The problem I have is that if he edits one or more of them and inputs an invalid choice no validation errors are shown. Instead, nothing happens (if I have `if changed_events.is_valid()` in the code) or I get "ValueError at /coding/assignment/3/
The EventRecord could not be changed because the data didn't validate." If the user puts in valid data, saving works just fine.

I would like to show validation errors on the page, the way it is already working when creating new entries.

Following my code:

The view (I'm not posting my whole view, as it's fairly complex and everything else is working fine. These are the parts responsible for what's not working):

```
##### Show already created events on the page
    current_article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
    EventFormSet = modelformset_factory(EventRecord, can_delete=True, exclude=('coder','article','url','last_updated'), extra=0)
    event_queryset = EventRecord.objects.filter(article__id=current_article.id).filter(coder=request.user.id)
    coded_events = EventFormSet(queryset=event_queryset, prefix="event_form")


elif 'save_changes' in request.POST:
            formset = CodingFormSet(prefix="coding_form")
            changed_events = EventFormSet(request.POST, prefix="event_form")
           # if changed_events.is_valid():

            instances = changed_events.save()


            try:
                history_record = ArticleHistory.objects.filter(article__id=paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0].id).filter(coder=request.user.id)[0]
                history_record.last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
                history_record.save()
            except:
                history_form = ArticleHistoryForm()
                article_history = history_form.save(commit=False)
                article_history.article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
                article_history.coder = request.user
                article_history.last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
                article_history.save()



            redirect_to = "?page=%s" % current_page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
```

The template:

```
{% for eventrecord in coded_events %}



            {{ eventrecord.id }}
            <div class="form-container">
                {% if eventrecord.non_field_errors %}
                {{form.non_field_errors}}
                {%endif%}

                {% for field in eventrecord %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                    <li>{{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?
Clearly Django is recognizing that something is going wrong, but why doesn't it show it in the template but creates an error-page? Why does nothing happen when I include the `is_valid()`?
I really don't know what I'm supposed to do, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, this was stupid:
Right after posting my question I saw the answer, after working days on it.

Here's what went wrong:

The queryset was passed to the template as `coded_events`.
During the `save_changes` operation, I renamed it to `changed_events`, which then couldn't be passed back to the template in case of validation errors.

After fixing that, everything works fine.